Gráfico geográfico
Estoy intentando hacer un gráfico del mundo donde aparezcan marcados en un color asociado a una leyenda y con unas frecuencias en números absolutos y otros países con otro color asociado a otra leyenda y también con frecuencias en números absolutos. Lo quiero hacer en r y lo que llevo hecho es esto:
mapa_mundo <- map_data("world")
paises_pharma <- read.xlsx("paises_bigpharma_wos_scopus.xlsx")
paises_pfizer <- read.xlsx("paises_pfizerorgate_wos_scopus.xlsx")
# Unir y crear gráfico
paises_combinados <- rbind(paises_pharma %>% mutate(Teorías = "Big Pharma"),
                           paises_pfizer %>% mutate(Teorías = "Pfizer"))
mapa <- merge(mapa_mundo, paises_combinados, by.x = "region", by.y = "Countries", all.x = TRUE)

ggplot(data = mapa[!is.na(mapa$Teorías) & !is.na(mapa$Count), ], aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = Teorías), alpha = 0.6) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue" = "Pfizer", "red" = "Big Pharma"), name = "Teorías") +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = as.numeric(Count)), alpha = 0.4) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "darkblue", name = "Count") +
  labs(title = "Artículos de Pfizer y Big Pharma en el mundo") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")

Y me da este error:

Scale for fill is already present. Adding another scale for fill,
which will replace the existing scale. Error in
scale_fill_gradient(): ! Discrete values supplied to continuous
scale. ℹ Example values: "Big Pharma", "Pfizer", "Big Pharma",
"Pfizer", and "Big Pharma" Run rlang::last_trace() to see where the
error occurred.

Si alguien me puede dar una pista de lo que puedo hacer se lo agradeceré enormemente

Al parecer el problema viene en scale_fill_gradient(). La función está diseñada para variables continuas mientras que al parecer en tu código hace referencia a una variable que detecta como discreta.
